# Link one target with multiply other targets

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I've this setup in my `Podfile` file

```
target "A" do
  pod "Pod1"
  target "ATests" do
    pod "Pod2"
  end
end

target "B" do
  pod "Pod3"
  target "BTests" do
    pod "Pod4"
  end
end

target "SharedTests" do
  pod "Pod5"
end
```

How do I link targets `ATests` and `BTests` with `SharedTests` but not `A` and `B`. Was hoping to use something like `link_with`, but that seems to be long gone.

My goal is to share code, not necessarily pods, between the test targets in my application.

Comment: You may use `def podsForA pod "pod1" pod "pod1-1" end`, `def podsForB pod "pod3" pod "pod3-1" end` to define groups of pods and then in `target "sharedTest" do podsForA podsForB pod "Pod5" end`? It depends really on which one is simpler.

Comment: How do you link the target `SharedTest` to `ATests`? I can only see that you handling the pods.

Comment: Note that its the code within `ShareTests` I want to access in `ATests`. The pods them selfs are not important at this stage.